# Popup inside the window

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, facebook, html

Right now I have a grid and each grid part/bit contains an image, the name of the item and different buttons that can delete the item from the mysql database and update the price. What I want to do know is that when a user say clicks on the image a window would pop up where extra information would be displayed. However it is not a pop up in a usual sense that it would create another window but rather a pop up within the current window/tab. E.g. When you press on a photo in Facebook it creates almost like a popup on which you can comment or change to the next photo. Does anyone have any idea on how to do this or at least what is the whole thing/process called?

Sorry if I can't give a proper name but I don't know it myself :/

Here is the code to what I have now. I would prefer an actual code solution but if you can lead me to where I should look for it I would also be happy. I tried looking online however everything I get is window pop ups.

```
<div class="boxes">
    <?php
    $ID = $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
    $con = mysql_connect("", "", "");

    if (!$con){
      die("Cannot connect: " . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("test", $con);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE member_id = $ID";

    $myData = mysql_query($sql, $con);

    $dir = 'Images';
    $symbol = '\\';
    $end = 'r.jpg';
    $currency = '£';

    while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) {
      $real_name = str_replace('_', ' ', $record['Name']);
      $result = $dir . $symbol . $record['Name'] . $end;
      $value = $currency . $record['price_now'];
      $link = $record['url'];

      echo "<div class = frame>";
      echo "<div class = bit-3>";
      echo "<div class = box>" . "<img src=" . $result . " alt=some_text>";
      echo "<br />";
      echo "<br />";
      echo $real_name;
      echo "<br />";
      echo "<br />";
      echo "Price now: " . $value;
      echo "<form action = member-profile-page.php method = post>";
      echo "Desired price: ";
      echo "<td>" . "<input type = text name = desired_price value = " . $record['desired_price'] . " </td>";
      echo "<td>" . "<input type = hidden name = hidden value = " . $record['Id'] . " </td>";
      echo "&nbsp;";
      echo "<td>" . "<input type = submit name = update value = Update" . " </td>";
      echo "<br />";
      echo "<br />";
      echo "<td>" . "<input type = submit name = delete value = Delete" . " </td>";
      echo "<br />";
      echo "<br />";
      echo "<td>" . "<input type = submit name = buy value = Buy" . " </td>";
      echo "</form>";
      echo "</div>";
      echo "</div>";
      echo "</div>";
    }

    if (isset($_POST['buy'])){

      $query = "select url from items where Id = '$_POST[hidden]'";
      if ($result = mysql_query($query)) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $code = $row['url'];
        echo "$code";
        header("Location: $code");
      }
    };

    if (isset($_POST['update'])){
      $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE items SET desired_price = '$_POST[desired_price]' WHERE Id = '$_POST[hidden]'";
      mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $con);
    };

    if (isset($_POST['delete'])){
      $DeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM items WHERE Id = '$_POST[hidden]'";
      mysql_query($DeleteQuery, $con);
    };

    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is only possible with js. No way of php!

Comment: and please change your profile image, or you will get banned!!

Comment: FYI: we've had a couple of complaints about your profile image. While you're free to express yourself within reason, keep in mind that this is a site for professionals and please keep the imagery appropriate for such a context.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for an overlay:

http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/index.html

or a modal:

https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

These are by no means the only examples; there are hundreds of such solutions. These will get you started, though. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What you think about is just a layer in the current browser viewport, having some controls to let the user handle it like a "desktop window".

There are quite a lot of JS frameworks offering handy solutions for this, i.e. [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/). Within there, look for "dialog"